# Swift: adding optionals Ints

Tags: swift, option-type

I declare the following:

```
var x:Int?
var y:Int?
```

and I'd like a third variable `z` that contains the sum of `x` and `y`. Presumably, as `x` & `y` are optionals, `z` must also be an optional:

```
var z:Int? = x + y
```

but this gives a complier error *"value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'"*

If I unwrap `x` & `y`:

```
var z:Int? = x! + y!
```

I get a run-time error as `x` & `y` are nil, so can't be unwrapped.

I can achieve the desired result as follows:

```
var z:Int?

if let x1 = x {
    if let y1 = y {
       z = x1+y1
    }
}
```

but this seems a bit verbose for adding together 2 integers! Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you want to ignore if either y or x is nil? Then use the ?? operator.

let z = (y ?? 0) + (x ?? 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take, I think it's cleaner:

```
let none:Int? = nil
let some:Int? = 2

func + (left: Int?, right:Int?) -> Int? {
    return left != nil ? right != nil ? left! + right! : left : right
}

println(none + none)
println(none + some)
println(some + none)
println(some + some)
println(2 + 2)
```

With results of:

```
nil
Optional(2)
Optional(2)
Optional(4)
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution IMO:

```
z = x.map { x in y.map { $0 + x } }
```

Did you know the map operator on `Optional<T>`? It is very nice.

Documentation says:

> If self == nil, returns nil. Otherwise, returns f(self!).

Comment: Good one. Or `flatMap`.

Comment: @AuRis yes you could, be `flatMap` returns an `Optional<T>` which is not needed in that case as we definitely return something when there is an actual value

Comment: This is the right way to be thinking about the problem, well done

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is:

```
if x && y {
    z = x! + y!;
}
```

Since they are all Optionals... there's really no way to avoid:

1. checking that they aren't `nil`
2. Unwrapping them before you add them.

Comment: *"Why do I want Optional Ints?"*: no reason - this is purely theoretical.

Comment: @AshleyMills this way will work but since Swift lang. should be  more clearer then Obj-C, this example will be hard to understand during maintenance. Make your code simple!

Comment: It seems like *optional chaining* would have been a nice solution, but that only works with object methods, properties, etc.

Comment: The question is about Swift - your code just doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

It depends exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you could do it with an optional tuple:

```
var xy: (Int, Int)?
var z: Int

if let (x1, y1) = xy {
    z = x1 + y1 // Not executed
}
xy = (3, 4)
if let (x1, y1) = xy {
    z = x1 + y1 // 7
}
```

**Update**
As @Jack Wu points out, this changes the semantics. If you were willing to be a bit more verbose, you could however do it as follows:

```
func optIntAdd(x: Int?, y: Int?) -> Int? {
    if let x1 = x {
        if let y1 = y {
            return x1 + y1
        }
    }
    return nil
}

operator infix +! { }
@infix func +! (x: Int?, y: Int?) -> Int?{
    return optIntAdd(x, y)
}

var x: Int?
var y: Int?
var z: Int?

z =  x +! y // nil
x = 1
z =  x +! y // nil
y = 2
z =  x +! y // 3
```

Not sure "+!" is a useful choice of name for the operator, but it would't let me choose "+?".

Comment: This changes the semantics of things...`xy` cannot be `(3, nil)`

Comment: Correct. I can't see how one would do that, other than by writing a func that took optional parameters and returned an optional, which seems a bit complex - as I said in the answer, "It depends exactly what you're trying to achieve."

Comment: Hmmm… operator overloading and a function to add 2 integers… not one of Swift's finest moments.

Comment: Ahh... but they are _not_ integers - they are optional integers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Someday, we'll have variadic generics. Until then, you need a pair of overloads for all arities.

```swift
var z = Optional(x, y).map(+)
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optional0: Wrapped0?, _ optional1: Wrapped1?)
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    self = .init((optional0, optional1))
  }

  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 5.5 Sum any optional values

```
infix operator +?: AdditionPrecedence

public func +? <T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T {
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs + rhs
    } else if let lhs = lhs {
        return lhs
    } else if let rhs = rhs {
        return rhs
    } else {
        return .zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

z = (x ?? 0) + (y ?? 0)

*** Worked on Xcode 9 ***

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation